# Can't add private IP (VPC) to new Google Cloud SQL instance with gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I've being trying to create a new CloudSQL instance with a private IP attached from the get go. The only thing documentation hints me is to add a VPC network. I'm trying to add the default one.

First I'm enabling the correct APIs / services to my project:

```
gcloud services enable servicenetworking.googleapis.com servicemanagement.googleapis.com --project=my-project
```

Then I'm trying to create the CloudSQL instance:

```
gcloud beta sql instances create cloudsql-instance-name --region=europe-west1 --project=my-project --network=projects/my-project/global/networks/default
```

However this gives me this non descriptive error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.instances.create) [INTERNAL_ERROR] Failed to create subnetwork. Please create Service Networking connection with service 'servicenetworking.googleapis.com' from consumer project '1234567890' network 'default' again.
```

Two questions:

1. Is this the correct way to add a private IP to an instance upon creation? Or are there other ways?
2. Why is it giving me this error and how can I resolve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need to create an "[Allocated IP ranges for services](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access#procedure)" and a "[Private connections to services](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access#creating-connection)" inside the VPC that you want to have CloudSQL Instance. (In your case is "default" VPC). Once you have both you should be able to create the MYSQL Instance.

Comment: Could You please tell more details about this. I mean why should we want to create allocated-ip range and private connections for cloud sql which is a google provided service

Comment: @YokeshT this diagram explains why you need to create allocated-ip range and private connections: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access#ip_address_range_size