# GCP Database Migration Service Test Step Error: Failed to create subnetwork

Tags: google-cloud-platform, database-migration

I'm tring migrate my Google Cloud RDS MySQL. I configured all the steps and had a test, got the error: Failed to create subnetwork. Please create Service Networking connection with service 'servicenetworking.googleapis.com' from consumer project 'xxx' network 'default' again.

I went through the diagnose guide, but found no solution about this error. Here's what I reviewed,
https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/diagnose-issues

Where should I start from?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at [Can't add private IP (VPC) to new Google Cloud SQL instance with gcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56957596/cant-add-private-ip-vpc-to-new-google-cloud-sql-instance-with-gcloud)

It's a VPC private connection service issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).